# I am not able to move a Button (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css, button

So I have recently been coding a game (a clone of the game agar.io), and I have run into this problem where I can't move a button. its stuck, even though if add left: X; and top: X; I have searched so many places for a fix, but can't find anything.
Here is the code:

```
<button style="width: 15%;float: left !important; left: 10px; and top: 10px;" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="btn btn-success">Select Skin <i class="fui-user"></i></button>
```

Thanks, sorry if its a bit unclear.

Comment: You need `position: absolute`, not `float: left`.

Comment: left/right:xx works along position:relative/absolute/fixed (eventually sticky) but not with static which is the default value ;)

Comment: Thank you a lot, this worked!

Comment: This is a Q&A site. I think there must be at least one question mark in the title or description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [box offset](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props) properties that you are using (`left` et al) only apply to *positioned* elements.

These are elements where the `position` property is set to a value other than `static`, but `static` is the default and you haven't changed it.

Look at [`absolute`, `fixed`, and `relative`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position).

Comment: If this answered your question, go ahead and click the green check mark under the voting area (the number to the left of the question).  This will mark it as "answered", give Quentin 15 rep, give you 2 rep, and let other users know that the problem has been fixed.